# Como pude hacer para que se termine este proceso después de cierto tiempo en docker-compose -up

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose

Con el archivo docker-compose.yml corro un server de selenium grid con el comando docker-compose up
como puede hacer para terminar ese proceso despues de cierto tiempo

docker-compose.yml

```
hub:

  image: selenium/hub

  ports:


    - "4444:4444"



chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome
  links:
    - hub
firefox:
  image: selenium/node-firefox
  links:
    - hub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo se `docker-compose` no tiene un mecanismo para hacer lo que pides

```
docker-compose up -d && sleep 2s && docker-compose down
```